# Calculating Previous months 'max' value from start whenever customer changes in a calender year

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to calculate the **previous months max** value for 2 different customers in a calender year , where the calculation(max) should begin new  whenever there is a change in customer. Hope the picture below will give more info :below is the mdx i am using.

case  when([Time].[year-month-date].CURRENTMEMBER is [Time].[year-month-date].&[jan]) or [Measures].[Base Value]<>([TIME].[year-month-date].CURRENTMEMBER.prevmember,[Measures].[Base Value])
 THEN  null
 ELSE MAX(PERIODSTODATE([TIME].[year-month-date].[month],[TIME].[year-month-  da[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u2EF.png)te].CURRENTMEMBER.PREVMEMBER),[Measures].[Sales]) END

**** BASE VALUE is just a number representing customer.

with this mdx i am getting the ”previous month” max value but i need to calculate  ”previous months” max value . I have used the case statement to make the ’jan’ month always null and also whenever there is change in customer(base value)

can someone help me in getting it.

Kind Regards

Mah

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFpK5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this’ll help as all I’ve done is tidy the syntax:

```
IIF(
([Time].[year-month-date].CURRENTMEMBER 
IS [Time].[year-month-date].&[jan]) 
OR
( [Measures].[Base Value]<>([TIME].[year-month-date].CURRENTMEMBER.prevmember,[Measures].[Base Value]) 
,NULL 
,MAX(PERIODSTODATE([TIME].[year-month-date].[month],[TIME].[year-month- daenter image description herete].CURRENTMEMBER.PREVMEMBER),[Measures].[Sales]) 
)
```

Comment: Hej whytheq,  thanks for the response but the above  MDX will give the max value of sales without considering the customer, but if you look att my image which i have uploaded i have clearly mentioned that whenever there is change in customer the max value should calcualted pertianing to that customer. You can see the image somewhere between the wordings.

Comment: @Mah instead of just using time in your calculation you need to also add in the CURRENTMEMBER of your customer dimension

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I was wrong in presenting my question, actually it is the same customer but has two different "basevalues", whenever the customer(same customer) changes his base value then max value should be calculated from that new base value.  mdx code which i tried to write .
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[maxpreviousmonths] AS
MAX({PERIODSTODATE
([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year],
     [Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER.PREVMEMBER)*
       ([Customer].[Customer Nr.].CURRENTMEMBER, [measures].[Base Value]},
     [Measures].[Sales Amount])

Comment: with this MDX too i am getting the same max value for the customer with 2 different base values, in simple terms the MDX is not respecting the condition which i have mentioned for base value(([Customer].[Customer Nr.].CURRENTMEMBER, [measures].[Base Value]). Could you check the image above in my first post i have corrected a bit.

**** customer will be carrying the same customer nr. even though base value changes.

I am attaching the corrected image plz check it. Hope image gives a a better clarification

Comment: thanks for the hint i have solved it by adding my base value in customer dimension to the currentmember level.